# Не могу загрузить картинку из сайта через C#

Tags: c#

```
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
           // client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(""), "");
            client.DownloadFile(new Uri("http://a0737524.xsph.ru/static.png"), "static.png");

        }
    }
}
```

Вот код, все работает, но картинка качаеться весом в 0 кб. Можете помочь?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Не воспроизводится](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvJPY.png). Проверяйте значит у себя соединение с этим сайтом. Также хочу напомнить, что `WebClient` является устаревшим компонентом в C#, это написано в документации.

Comment: У меня тоже всё скачалось. Это UI приложение или консоль? Откуда выдран этот кусок кода? Проблема за пределами показанного кода.